# Ctrl-C not killing process in CMD.EXE

Tags: windows-7, command-line, cmd.exe, kill

I've had this issue for a while even after reinstalling. Issue happens after I reinstall all my programs and not in a fresh Windows install (obviously). Might have to spin up a VM and install each program 1 by 1. I suspect it's Git for Windows with it's mini Cygwin wrapper causing this issue.

Anyway the issue is basically pressing Ctrl-C does not kill the running process. However when I run cmd.exe or Git Bash or administrator Ctrl-C works great again. Disabling UAC seems to break it again.

I've made a video of the issue [here](http://youtu.be/46l4RHB0w_E).

Many thanks.