# Windows 10: CMD.exe cannot stop process with CTRL+C

Tags: windows-10, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, cmd.exe

Well, basically the title says it.
The issue is very similar to:

[Ctrl-C not killing process in CMD.EXE](https://superuser.com/q/766325/281154)

and

[Windows 10 CMD: Ctrl + C not killing processes?](https://superuser.com/q/955969/281154)

I could just assign the bounty to one of these questions, but both already have answers that seem to have worked for OPs and do not work for me. So posting separately.

Symptoms:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does not work in cmd.exe
- It does not work for any process (for example ping 8.8.8.8 /t ). So I do not think this is process specific
- Hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> multiple times does not help
- Resetting cmd.exe to default settings does not change behavior
- When running cmd.exe as administrator <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>  works, but this is not an acceptable solution. I cannot afford to run every script as admin
- Running cmd.exe in default and legacy mode produces the same result (CTRL+C does not work)

Additional info:

- OS: Windows 10 enterprise
- Settings of cmd.exe:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried repairing Windows?

Comment: Do you have installed any keyboard mapping product such as AutoHotKey?

Comment: Or Clavier+ . A test shows that it handles the Ctrl-C keypress before CMD sees it.

Comment: @harrymc, DrMoishe Pippik I have Autohotkey installed. I've tried first disabling and then uninstalling it with no success. Also Autohotkey does not explain why CTRL+C works when cmd.exe is run as Administrator....

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is if you start `cmd.exe` with the `start /b` command, since that disables Ctrl+C, as the help text for `start.exe` says:

```
B           Start application without creating a new window. The
            application has ^C handling ignored. Unless the application
            enables ^C processing, ^Break is the only way to interrupt
            the application.
```

In my tests, I can't kill a `start /b ping 8.8.8.8` with Ctrl+C. It looks like it's worked, because I see a prompt, but it's still pinging away in the background.

See [this answer](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/5460#issuecomment-617944520) for how it was worked around in the Windows Terminal application.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: @DavidPostill these questions are not duplicates - as this question says, "The issue is very similar to [Windows 10 CMD: Ctrl + C not killing processes?](https://superuser.com/questions/1409521/windows-10-cmd-exe-cannot-stop-process-with-ctrlc/1734962?noredirect=1#comment2685465_1734962), but both already have answers that seem to have worked for OPs and do not work for me. So posting separately." Closing either as a duplicate of the other seems wrong to me. However this answer (the same answer) is a possible answer (not the only answer) to both.